# Why isn't my audio working?

Tags: 11.04, sound

Why isn't my audio working in 11.04? If anyone knows, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add more information, what video card, what audio player are you using, have you tried any steps to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be more specific. That could have a 100 causes. What do your logs say? What do the sound preferences say? Does your soundcard show in the device list? Is the problem limited to a few applications or a certain filetype / pysical output on your pc? Have you upgraded your system or is it freshly installed? Does the pulsaudio-daemon run?

I'm taking a wild guess here and say: It doesn't work in Amarok only. If so install libxine-gnome.

Comment: Hrm. I don't know exactly what I did. But I went to Preferences -> Sound, and changed absolutely nothing. Yet somehow my sound IS working now. Either way if you hadn't mentioned the sound preferences it probably wouldn't work. Well thank you for your help. Also sorry for the trouble. Hope I didn't  bother you.

Comment: Of course you didn't bother. I wouldn't be on askubuntu if I wasn't willing to help. You just gave to little information to of a real help to you. Glad it worked out nonetheless.